# Problema SELENIUM al intentar conectar al driver firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;
import interfaz.interfaz;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

/**
 *
 * @author Josel
 */
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       WebDriver driver;
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
       driver =new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.get("www.google.com");
       driver.close();

    }

}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto firefox se abre pero  no sale la pagina que estoy poniendo y se queda en blanco , se abre una subventana preguntandome si guardo firefox.exe

Answer (score 1):

En esta linea debes indicar el webdriver de firefox, no el ejecutable de la aplicacion.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
```

Si estas fijando la propiedad como gecko, debes indicarle el webdriver descargado desde [aqui](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Cambiando esa linea por algo parecido a esto:

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "\\dondeesteladescarga\\geckodriver_v0.18.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

Descarga el geckodriver de:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Intentalo asi:

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   WebDriver driver;
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/ruta/geckodriver.exe");
   driver =new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("www.google.com");
   driver.close();
}}
```

Deberia funcionar sin problemas